# Taking an RTSP camera stream and transcoding it?

Tags: wifi, camera, rtsp

I have an aquarium camera which streams over RTSP. Unfortunately when I access the IP address, the stream wants to load a VLC plugin. I want to be able to share this stream with others without the need to install software or plugins etc. The only way I can find to do this is either use a paid for service (not ideal) or take the stream, transcode it to a web friendly stream, making the new stream accessible.

Is it possible to make a raspberry pi the middle man here? I found some information but not sure if it's the best solution:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151012014829/http://www.videolan.org:80/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html

The camera is connected via USB to a wifi hub box which is in turn connected to my home network via wifi. I would be looking at connecting the Pi to my router via cable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can store streams on the raspberry pi drive by:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://yourRtspStreamSource" -hls_time 3 -hls_wrap 10 "yourOutputDir/streaming.m3u8"
```

And then, re-stream streaming.m3u8 over HTTP:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "yourOutputDir/streaming.m3u8" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -threads 0 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 512k -bufsize 640k -maxrate 640k -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -tune film -acodec aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000?pkt_size=1316
```

---

I haven't tested it but must work. It gives the RTSP streams and saves to `streaming.m3u8` then re-stream the `streaming.m3u8` to your localhost.

---

More information:

[Convert rtsp-stream into http stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836137/convert-rtsp-stream-into-http-stream)
[Re-stream using FFmpeg](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-restream-using-ffmpeg-with-wowza-streaming-engine)

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. This appears to be working. The part I'm stuck on is accessing the re-stream, which is probably just my lack of knowledge in Linux and networks! I have the following outputs: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1KnrMyZtQ_oZ6SPeKixDkFY_JlPhZfnfY

Comment: I just skim what you did and my suggestion is fire commands as `root` user by running `su`.